# Best environment to install centos 7 on laptop to use system as web server

Tags: centos7

I want to install centos 7 on laptop to use system as a web server.

I'll use this server for hosting a django project, so I need to install python and django after centos installation manually.

Comment: Should I use Basic Web Server environment for this? I don't want gui for same.

Comment: The question is not clear. Just install centos in a VM or as the primary system, and then setup a web-server with django. What is the question exactly?   Anyway, flagging this as off-topic as  (a) this has nothing to do with programming (b) is to broad to answer.

Comment: Thanks rth, 

My question is "While installing centos 7 which software selection (environment) will be best for me to use this system as a web server?" Please see below image to know what are options I have.

http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CentOS-7-Installation-12.png

Comment: If you are comfortable working without a GUI, I would say to go with "Minimal install" or a "Basic web server " which will probably install LAMP (apache, mysql, PHP). You can always install the packages you need later. BTW, I see the problem now, there just don't seem to be easily accessible documentation about centos. I love how https://www.centos.org/docs/ just stops at version 5.

Comment: Actually, it's in the Red Hat documentation    https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-package-selection-x86.html  , although it doesn't provide much details.

Comment: Yes rth, I agree with you.
I'm going to use "Minimal install", then install other requirements and setup a web-server with django.

Thank you for your help.